# discord.js SyntaxError: Unexpected token?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm doing the discord.js getting started bot but I always get this error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token?
[image: the error code i get]

This is the code I used, actually just copy and paste from their tutorial just switched to dotenv for the token...

```
 // Require the necessary discord.js classes
require("dotenv").config();
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

// Login to Discord with your client's token
client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

These are the versions of discord.js and dotenv I'm using. Node version is 12.8.0

```
    "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^13.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0"
  }
```

Already thanks for your help guys!

Comment: What version of nodejs are you running?

Comment: Looks like an issue with your version of javascript. I'd check that you're on at least targeting es6. looks like a simple issue where your compiler isn't understanding the nullish coalescing operator. Or just change it to ||

Comment: @UnholySheep Node version is 12.8.0

Comment: @jesper 12.8 is pretty old and being deprecated by most packages. I'd recommend updating: https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: @DarrowHartman Had to upgrade to at least version 16.6.0 to be able to use discord.js properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the first thing to note is that your error is coming from `node_modules`. That means that the code that is erroring is code that you've imported from `npm` to do something. Because it's not your code and rather third party code that probably works, that means that the error most likely has to do with either your version of that code or the way you're using that package is incorrect.

My best guess would be that it has to do with some advanced syntax that the package is using, but that errors on your machine because you have version incompatibility. I'd recommend updating your node version and trying again. Let us know if that fixes the problem!

**Download latest node version: https://nodejs.org/en/download/**

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you guys! The only weird thing was, that i used nvm for the node version and the latest version it installed was only 14.18.0. Do you know why?

Comment: @jesper 14.18.0 is the current LTS version and should be sufficient for the `??` operator

Comment: @UnholySheep yes it was, but then discord.js itself was saying it needs atleast node 16.6.0 to work properly.