# SyntaxError : Unexpected token keeps popping up

Tags: discord.js

I keep getting this error all the time but it seems to work fine on any other bot that I have, any ideas?

````
    const token = this.client.token ?? this.client.accessToken;
                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'```
````

Comment: The same question was asked yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69411544/discord-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

Comment: @UnholySheep I use repl.it so idk if there is like a way to update the version of Node.js on there.

Comment: The proposed duplicate has a solution for repl.it in its answers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.js SyntaxError: Unexpected token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69411544/discord-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

Comment: Tysm @NotTrixxie

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This error you received is because the Node version you are running doesn't supports the [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) which is introduced in Node.js `v14`.

Assuming you have an outdated version of Node.js running on your machine, to fix this, you should upgrade to at least Node.js v16 as this is **required** if you want to use Discord.js `v13`. (Stated in [Documentation of Discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome)).

Head over to https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/ and choose the right installation package for your system.